# ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'students' (0)

Tags: mysql

Every time I start the server I am able to execute the first command and then I couldn't do anything and I can't connect to the database.Please help me resolving this.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBGSu.png)

Comment: check your database service is running properly or not :)

Comment: Yes it is running properly

Comment: ok , accept my answer as helpful :)

Comment: i said the database service is running properly and issue not resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong command. `connect` will try to connect to another database server. You'll want to try `use students` instead. For reference, see the [list of MySQL commands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html).